# Does MySQL have the concept of "this" database?

Tags: mysql

When writing a query, can I reference the current database's name, sort of like with the **this** keyword in Java? I am writing a script that I will run against several similar databases, and I need to query the `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table with the `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` column in my `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT DATABASE()` gives you the selected database
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html